# How to hide custom sidebar on mobile

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets, mobile

So I have made some customizations to my wordpress premium theme,but I want to hide those customizations on mobile versions. I've tried to add `id` of widget inside `@media` with `display:none;` but nothing, still active.

This is the code for the second sidebar I've made

inside theme's `functions.php`:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
'name'=>'Sidebar Left',
 'id'   => 'sidebar-left',  
      'description'   => 'Widget Area left',  
      'before_widget' => '<div id="sidleft" class="sidleft2">',  
      'after_widget'  => '</div>',  
      'before_title'  => '<h2>',  
      'after_title'   => '</h2>'  
     ));  
    }
```

Inside `index.php`:

```
<div id= "sidebar-left" class="sidleft2"> <? php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Left')): endif;?></div >
```

How to hide it ?

The 2nd thing I made with customizations is from vertical posts (latests) I've made 4 blocks inline. Here I changed `height` and `width`. In default version of theme thumbs are small and no visible on mobile, only the title is shown.

Inside `@media` is this : `ul.headlines li img`,  which hides those images, but the problem is that the changes I made now leave some gaps so its the title and below the title is the area where image should appear and since the line of code `ul.headlines li img` (`display:none;`) is used they don't, and only the place where the image should be is shown.What I want is to remove that gap on mobiles, like in default theme, but after 2 days no luck .

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide lots of details on your code. Something like this should work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  #sidebar-left {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: If it still doesn't work, add a !important, like this: display: none !important;

Comment: Hi Christian, what code exactly is missing so i can add it..This code doesnt seems to work..i tried that

Comment: Using the site responsivepx.com and setting the width there up to 599px width this sidebar doesnt show up.But using the sites like ipadpeek.com and similar ones, sidebar shows up. So i m little confused about it, as i want to disable it for every mobile device.

Comment: 2nd thing as you can see in screenshot ( http://i42.tinypic.com/fumiw7.jpg) image is resized and there is a gap. In default theme look that image doesnt show up at all , and only the title is there.Inside theme function i v add a new image size for my needs,if i denied it on mobile i see a blank space where image should be, and i tried also to resize it to 100% width but no luck..i m newbie at this, so something i m doing wrong ..Thanks for the help

Comment: Can I see the site somewhere? I imagine another element is involved.